# Off-page Sliding Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple off-page sliding navigation however I am stack on some codes mostly CSS.

I am trying to create a 3D effect instead of a simple slide effect which hides and unhide the menu on the sidebar.

Here's my current JSFIDDLE work: http://jsfiddle.net/je9fa6zc/

What I want is to create a 3D slide in effect that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/f9bdm1te/2/

So I tried to copy some CSS from this JSFIDDLE however I did not get what I want. 
See my updated CSS after copying some codes on the 3D slide in effect JSFIDDLE.

```
#site-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px; /* Temp: Simulates a tall page. */

    -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
    perspective: 1500px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
}


#site-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease all;
    transition: .3s ease all;

    padding: 5% 0; /* Temp: Just spacing. */
}

#site-menu {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    background: #428bca;
    padding: 15px;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotateY(-90deg);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotateY(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#site-wrapper.show-nav #site-canvas {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
    transform: translateX(300px);

    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Would you mind checking where did i went wrong?

If also you could update my JSFIDDLE so that I can visualize it?

Comment: NOTE: without the NEW CSS added here's what my codes look like: http://jsfiddle.net/6unvc0ua/4/

Comment: I understand however this is CSS only not JavaScript or jQuery. I just want to create an 3D slide in animation that looks like this. http://jsfiddle.net/f9bdm1te/2/ which is mainly CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some CSS to your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je9fa6zc/21/).

```
/* transition the menu with perspective on "show-nav" */
#site-wrapper.show-nav #site-menu {

    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;

    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
            transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

By default the menu is rotated inwards by 90 degrees, and when the show-nav-class is applied - a transition is made on both the sliding div and the menu itself. This way the menu can be rotated with perspective to its original 0 degrees.

Check it out and see if it's what you're after.